# How to load specific version assembly from GAC in ASP Net VNext

Tags: asp.net-core

I can load the assembly from GAC in ASP.Net 5 application. but i couldn't load the specific version. please have a look on my codes.

```
[project.json]

    "frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": { },
    "aspnetcore50": { },
    "net45": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {               
            "System.Web.Mvc": "5.0.0.0"
        }

    }
}
```

In above code in project.json file, i have tried to load MVC 5.but it doesn't load in reference instead of that, it will show like with corrupted symbol. Even these assemblies are available in GAC. i have tried with some other assemblies. Am getting the same error only.

In case if i load without version details. it will automatically load the lowest version of MVC. i.e., MVC 3 is the lowest version in my machine. that was loaded in reference.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mvc 5 isn't supported with .Net 5 to my knowledge; what are you trying to do? Assemblies that you have currently in the GAC also will not be compatible with `aspnetcore50`, as it is a very different framework.

Comment: @MattDekrey yes you are correct, we couldn't load MVC 5 with aspnetcore50 since it was very different framework. so that i have loaded this assembly under .netframework 4.5 in project.json file. i am not telling only issue with MVC assembly. this would reproduce if you refer an assembly which was available in two version in GAC like 1.0.0.0 and 2.0.0.0, it will load automatically lowest one. but i want load exact same version which i gave in that assembly reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug confirmed by ASP.NET team. please find the details about in here 
https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/1688#issuecomment-95671082

Thanks